# R column to row for table

Tags: r

I have a table:

```
table(sex)

 male  female 
58     48
```

I would like to put it like that:

```
male   58
female 48
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap with `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(table(sex))
#     sex Freq
#1 female   42
#2   male   58
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
sex <- sample(c("male", "female"), 100, replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is that possible to have exactly that i requested without #?

Comment: @E.bl Have you even tried the solution? The `#` are used in SO posts to display the output, thereby making clear that these lines are not part of the code. Here's a [demo](https://ideone.com/5qWYmq) of akrun's answer.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. I need that for write an function and i don't work

Comment: @E.bl Maybe [this variant](https://ideone.com/U2c4Mm) helps:  `x <- \`colnames<-\`(as.data.frame(table(sex)), NULL); rownames(x) <- x[,1]; x <- x[,2,drop=FALSE]`.

Comment: @E.bl If you want to preserve the `table` class (although it is generally more difficult to handle than a `data.frame`) you can try `t(t(table(sex))`.

Comment: sounded like E.bi wanted to get rid of the # table decorators.