# Function with warning message

Tags: r

I would like to know why I have a warning message.

My code was

```
 univ_quali<-function(dataset){ print(cbind((addmargins(prop.table(dataset))), t(t(dataset))))}
> univ_quali(table(sex))
       [,1] [,2]
1 0.5471698   58
2 0.4528302   48
```

It work but I have:

```
Warning message:
In cbind((addmargins(prop.table(dataset))), t(t(dataset))) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combining unequal columns in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531471/combining-unequal-columns-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning does not occur if you simply remove the `addmargins()` function:

```
univ_quali <- function(dataset){cbind(prop.table(dataset), t(t(dataset)))}
univ_quali(table(sex))
#            [,1] [,2]
#female 0.4245283   45
#male   0.5754717   61
```

**data** (similar to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36674305/4770166))

```
set.seed(24)
sex <- sample(c("male", "female"), 106, replace=TRUE)
```